# Repositioning the caret before inserting text via htmlbutton addon in Ckeditor instance

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, cursor

My goal using htmlbuttons addon for CKeditor is to insert the html code at the very beginning of the textbox content, despite the position of the caret. I adapted the script shown below (found here), but it does not work, so I need to know what could be wrong.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'htmlbuttons',
{ init : function( editor )

{ for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
  var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[name]; }
```

above I get the id (which is the same as the name) - verified

```
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
if (input.setSelectionRange) {
input.focus();
input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}
else if (input.createTextRange) {
var range = input.createTextRange();
range.collapse(true);
range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
range.select();
}
}

function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}
```

above is the script I found here to reposition the caret (cursor).

```
var buttonsConfig = editor.config.htmlbuttons;
    if (!buttonsConfig)
        return;

    function createCommand( definition )
    {
        return {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                
                instanceId = (instance.name);
                    
setCaretToPos(document.getElementById(instanceId),0);
```

line above should position the caret at the beginning of ckeditor textbox, but it does not work.

```
editor.insertHtml( definition.html );
            }
        };
    }

    // Create the command for each button
    for(var i=0; i<buttonsConfig.length; i++)
    {
        var button = buttonsConfig[ i ];
        var commandName = button.name;
        editor.addCommand( commandName, createCommand(button, editor) );

        editor.ui.addButton( commandName,
        {
            label : button.title,
            command : commandName,
            icon : this.path + button.icon
        });
    }
} //Init

} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better solution:

Replace the line "SetCaretToPos..." with this code:

```
(function( cursorManager ) {                
var range = editor.createRange();
range.moveToPosition( range.root, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END );
//OR range.moveToPosition( range.root, CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_START );
editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
}( window.cursorManager = window.cursorManager || {}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer - replace the line "SetCaretToPos..." with this code:

```
editor.focus();
var selection = editor.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRanges()[0];
var pCon = range.startContainer.getAscendant('p',true);
var newRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range(range.document);
newRange.moveToPosition(pCon, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_START);
newRange.select();
```

that's it. It inserts the code at the very begining - disregarding the cursor position.